# how to know which user has logged in to my ios app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am new to coding for the iphone. I have coded a lsogin page which communicates with my server and checks if the user exists and logs them in if the uername and password are correct.

But how do i know which user has logged in so i know which user profile to retrieve?

Does anyone know any good tutorials or documentation on this please.

Comment: I'm confused, if they are authenticating to your server and your server is the one ensuring that they have provided the correct credentials it sounds like you would know exactly who logged in and what information to return?

Comment: i mean with php i would store the member_id or something in a session, is there something simmilar on the iphone. All i've done is check to make sure the username and password match and then send them to the next view.

Comment: Make sure you aren't sending that password off to a server without encrypting it.

Comment: im not at the moment just to test it. that is also on my list to add. Just created myself a test user in my database which im using :) This is all new to me so just going one step at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store any value you get back from the server on the device using several methods. Two that come to mind are.

1. Store the member information in NSUserDefaults.
2. Store the member information in shared cookie storage.

I think you should look into proper user session tracking on the iPhone since lack of knowledge here can lead to security holes.

Comment: Thanks ill look in to both of them.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to achieve what the asker was asking for. And the easiest way to get your log in view in your app taken care of is by using a `BALogInView`. It is simple to use and allows for quick development. https://github.com/brandonaskea/BALogInView